# How to add and remove an HTML class at a specific time after page load?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add and remove an HTML class (.flashy-design) to an HTML element (ID bland-html-element) a few seconds after page load.

My attempts below don't inject the class.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    function addFlashyDesign() {
        var element = document.getElementById("bland-html-element");
        element.classList.add("flashy-design");
    }
}, 3000);
```

or

```
function startDelay(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        function addFlashyDesign() {
            var element = document.getElementById("bland-html-element");
            element.classList.add("flashy-design");
        }
    }, 3000);
};

window.onload = "startDelay();";
```

Ideas?

Comment: Do you want it to be added after 3 seconds and then after next 3 seconds it should be added and then in next 3 it will remove again and so on ?

Comment: @mzparacha No, It seems he want execute the function only after page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is in the code. The main mistake you made was not using the callback function as you should.

```js
let element = document.getElementById("bland-html-element");

// show after 2 seconds
// RECOMMENDATION: use window.setTimeout instead of setTimeout
// NOTE: use a callback function, not an embedded named function
window.setTimeout(function() {
     element.classList.add("flashy-design");
}, 2000);

// hide after 3 seconds
window.setTimeout(function() {
     element.classList.remove("flashy-design");
}, 3000);
```

```css
#bland-html-element{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
#bland-html-element.flashy-design{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bland-html-element"></div>
```

PS: Don't use `window.onload`. Use `window.addEventListener('load', function(){})` instead. I didn't embed it after a load event in my example, but you should or you risk running the code before `bland-html-element` exists in your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `window.onload` for your `setTimeout()` method since it'll self-invoke on page load.

You also don't need to nest so many functions like that. You can either:

Create a **named function** outside the `setTimeout()` method then reference the function name on the method like this:

```
function delayFunc() {
  var element = document.getElementById("bland-html-element");
  element.classList.add("flashy-design");
}

setTimeout(delayFunc, 3000); // The above function will be invoked after 3 seconds
```

### Or

Create an **anonymous function** within the `setTimeout()` method itself like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var element = document.getElementById("bland-html-element"); 
  element.classList.add("flashy-design");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Kind of misleading function name, startDelay, but it happens after the delay.

Comment: @Andy The window.onload was his second attempt.

Comment: @MatthewPage Let me change that to some other ambiguous name.

Comment: Why not something useful like flashyElement() ?

Comment: @MatthewPage Bro lol This is just a dummy snippet. He can change it to whatever he wants lol

Comment: @MatthewPage If there's one thing I've learned in programming (and life in general) is that nothing is ever good enough unless you want it to be good enough. #inspiring

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is that, in both examples, you have a nested function - `addFlashyDesign` - that you are not calling. Instead, extract the that function and attach a function to the window onload listener. When this function is called it starts the timeout which calls `addFlashyDesign` after 3s.

You should keep the `window.onload` if, as you mention in your question, you want to add the class after the page has loaded.

> [The load event on the window object](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded#window-onload) triggers when the whole page is loaded including styles, images and other resources.

```
function addFlashyDesign() {
    var element = document.getElementById("bland-html-element");
    element.classList.add("flashy-design");
}

window.onload = () => setTimeout(addFlashyDesign, 3000);
```